# Kendo UI Chart Category Axis Labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Is there a way to add the line break in the client side ? 
For example, I want the category axis label to be displayed as:

```
JUN   
2012
```

But my database (server) returns it as `"JUN 2012"` and I don't want to add `\n` there, but want to achieve it from client side.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

First Solution 
Try converting the date strings to objects and use \n in format

Link http://dojo.telerik.com/@harsh/iBaHe

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  categoryAxis: [{
    labels: {
      format: "{0:MMM \n yyyy}"
    },
    categories: [new Date("Jun 2011"), new Date("Jun 2012"), new Date("Jun 2013")]
  }],
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
});
```

Comment: But in my example, the categories are not static. Its the return of a method.
[eg: chartData.categories]
Will this work here ?

Comment: @SharathSubramaniam yes it will work. The only thing you need to do is to convert the array of date strings returned from your function to array of date objects...